# Value checking Loop for Winddirection/ Windspeed in R

Tags: r, loops

Hey Guys I´m looking for a simple loop which goes over my data frame which looks something like this
 [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ggUPR.png)

I would need a loop which checks if column  Winddirection and Windspeed == 0

If both Variables are 0 its okay

If both Variables are not 0 its okay

If one of the Variables is 0 and the other is not 0  store the Lines in a new Vector

and print "In Line XY is an error"

Answer (score 0):

here is one method

```
df$Error <- with(df,ifelse(Windspeed==0 & Windirection!=0 | Windspeed!=0 & Windirection==0, "Error", ""))
```

output

```
> df
  Windspeed Windirection error
1         0            0      
2         0            0      
3         1            2      
4         0            2 Error
5         1            2      
6         1            2      
7         1            2
```

---

data:

```
df <- data.frame(Windspeed=c(0,0,1,0,1,1,1),Windirection=c(0,0,2,2,2,2,2))
```

Answer (score 0):

Another method....

If you just want to look at the data

```
library(dplyr)

df <- data.frame(Windspeed = c(0, 0, 5.52, 0, 5.86, 6.02, 6.07, 4.56),
                 Windirection = c(0, 0, 280, 279, 275, 276, 280, 0))

df %>% 
  filter((Windspeed == 0 & Windirection != 0) | (Windspeed != 0 & Windirection == 0))
```

Or as a function to display the text you want

```
check_data <- function (df_dat) {
  error_lines <- which((df_dat[,"Windspeed"] == 0 & df_dat[,"Windirection"] != 0) | (df_dat[,"Windspeed"] != 0 & df_dat[,"Windirection"] == 0))
  error_output <- paste0("In Line ", error_lines, " is an error\n")
  cat(error_output)
}

check_data(df)
```

Comment: Thank you this might help:)